# nginx rate limiting: unknown directive limit_req_zone

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rate-limiting

I'm trying to set up a rate limit for bots using my website, but if I add

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
```

or anything of the sort to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in the `http` block, before the includes I get

```
user@srv:~$ sudo service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "limit_req_zone" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:11
```

I can't figure out why this is or where else to look for issues...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What version of nginx is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you are using an ancient version of nginx (< 0.7.21) or [ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) module is not compiled into your nginx build (which is a bit odd). Run `nginx -V 2>&1 | grep --colour=auto limit` to check if maybe it's been disabled at build.

Comment: thanks. indeed, it was compiled without the module for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the `ubuntu` tag in your question, please try to `apt install nginx-full` -- instead of `nginx-light`, which is built `--without-http_limit_req_module`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case location directive configure syntax issue. the word "zone" was missing

```
http {

    include mime.types;
        limit_req_zone $request_uri zone=test_zone:10m rate=1r/s;

    server {

           listen   443 ssl;
           http2 on;
           server_name  192.168.0.111;
           ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/self.cert;
           ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/self.key;

           root /bloggingtemplate/;

          # index  index.html index.php;

           location / {
               limit_req zone=test_zone;
              }
```

nginx -t -- to check config syntax which was ok